# How to handle a dialogue appearing while getting logout of the application

Tags: security, selenium-webdriver, dialog

In my web application, I am getting a dialogue with an `OK` button and a `Cancel` button.

Can anybody suggest how to click the `ok` button on this dialogue programmatically?

Comment: not able to add screenshot..it has two buttons ok and cancel, I want to press ok button on this dialogue, how to do that?

Comment: if its an alert use `driver.switchTo().alert()` and use `accept()` or `dismiss()` methods as per your requirement.

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow! Your question came to me in a review queue to help improve questions.  I've done some of this: I took your comments and edited it into the question - for future reference you can edit those things in yourself. Also, here is the editing help - particularly adding images(http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#images) To make this question really useful for anyone finding it in future, you could add some information about what code you have tried and what the results were.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try by switching to alert and accept it or cancel it.

```
Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
alert.accept();
```

Or

```
alert.dismiss();
```

If the alert takes time to load, you need to wait for it. For example as below:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent()).accept();
```

Comment: Hi Nitin ..I am getting one exception..could not able to post here as there is a limit..

Comment: Add the exception few lines. What exception is it?

Comment: Capabilities [{platform=XP, acceptSslCerts=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, databaseEnabled=true, browserName=firefox, handlesAlerts=true, browserConnectionEnabled=true, webStorageEnabled=true, nativeEvents=false, rotatable=false, locationContextEnabled=true,

Comment: Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.UnhandledAlertException: Modal dialog present: Do you want to logout? 
Please close your browser after logging out.
Build info: version: '2.41.0', revision: '3192d8a', time: '2014-03-27 17:18:15'

Comment: It worked absolutely fine very first time, second time and onwards it failed.

Comment: @HarshNigam, Please check my edited answer. I think it is taking time before you find the alert and accept it.

Comment: Hi Nitin ..i have been able to solve the problem..your answer is now working fine. thanks a lot buddy for the prompt response.